# Assigning and Deleting Pointers

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, multidimensional-array

Okay, so here's the context. I've been up for almost a day straight now working on the legendary 8-puzzle problem. I have my heuristics down and my A_star algorithm down. We are required by the project spec to solve it using three different heuristic values. I can solve it for any one of the three individually, but when I go to solve them in succession, I get a ridiculous loop, and it never finds the correct successor state.

I *believe* my problem is with my pointers. I have a class, State, as defined below that has an int** array and a pointer to a State (its parent).

EDIT: I have to use int** as defined by the project specification, otherwise I would gladly use a pointer.

```
State   (int **bd, State* prnt);
State   (const State& other);
~State  ();
```

I am then declaring them as such:

```
State::State(int **bd, State* prnt) {

// allocate the board
board = new int*[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    board[i] = new int[3];
}

// fill in the board
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        board[i][j] = bd[i][j];
        //board[i][j] = 
    }
}

// set the parent
parent = prnt;
```

}

```
State::State(const State& other) {
// allocate the board
board = new int*[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    board[i] = new int[3];

State::~State() {
//std::cout << "Deconstructing " << this << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    delete board[i];
delete [] board;
delete parent;
parent = other.parent;
```

}

```
State::~State() {
//std::cout << "Deconstructing " << this << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    delete board[i];
delete [] board;
delete parent;
```

}

```
State& State::operator=(const State &rhs) {
if (&rhs == this) {
    return *this;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    delete board[i];
}
delete [] board;

// allocate the board
board = new int*[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    board[i] = new int[3];
}

// fill in the board
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        //board[i][j] = rhs.board[i][j];
        board[i][j] = rhs.getIntAtCoor(j, i);
    }
}

//delete parent;
// set the parent
parent = rhs.parent;

// set g
g = rhs.g;
f = rhs.f;
hType = rhs.hType;

return *this;
```

}

I don't give the exact declarations -- some of it is simple like int = int. I just can't quite figure it out. I feel like either my *delete parent* is wrong or my *parent = other.parent* is wrong (or both).

Thank you for your time and help,

Tyler

Comment: Don't use dynamic arrays. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: You do not delete a pointer, you delete pointee, an object pointed by a pointer.

Comment: In modern C++ you should avoid the `new` operator, and never use the `delete` operator.  Obviously this doesn't apply to really low-level stuff (allocators, memory pools, smart pointers, etc), but you don't often write those.

Comment: @deft_code Okay, so then I'd just remove all of my instances of `delete parent`, but what about the instances where I iterate through the int** and delete each cell? Would I want to not delete there as well?

Comment: @mloskot: if you want to get _really_ pendantic: you **do** delete a pointer, but you only _deallocate_ the pointee.  In either case pedantic chest thumping isn't helping anyone.

Comment: @deft_code There is nothing pedantic in my comment. Getting things straight and precisely helps to understand them. Also, If you don't use terminology of the domain you work with, you are on the straight way to shot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading your code-style may force the errors to evaporate.  In other words `new` and `delete` are error prone and should be avoided when better alternative exists.

For management of the cells consider:

- `std::shared_ptr`: can be used to void the `delete` calls
- `std::vector` can be used to avoid the `new` and `delete` calls
  Note you should use it like `std::vector<int> board( 3 * 3 )` and `board.at( x + y * 3 )`.
- And best of all just use a static array `int board[3][3]`.  No allocation at all.

Also child states do not own their parent states.  It's the other way around.  So child states shouldn't delete their parents.  You can still safely keep a parent pointer, but make sure you cleanup the children before you allow a parent to go out of scope (deleted or otherwise).  All of this cleaning and deleting doesn't neccessarily involve new at all.  Your `State` class looks small enough that is doesn't matter if they are copied by value.  In which case just have the parent use a `std::vector<State> m_children` and the compiler will take care of the rest.

Comment: See, I wrote it all without a `delete parent` and it worked fine up until trying to run it with three different heuristics right in a row. It will finish the first heuristic fine, but gets stuck in the second. Do you see anything in any of my declarations that might cause this behavior?

Comment: @TylerBell: try running your code after commenting out all `delete` calls. See if that fixes it, which would confirm memory errors.  Other than that, the behavior you describe sounds like you have a global or static variable somewhere that is misbehaving.

Comment: Thank you for not recommending `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` for use as a matrix.  Locality of data would likely be terrible and the performance hit significant.  That said, don't use `at()` in a tight loop.  `at()` performs bounds checking.  Of course, it depends on how performance sensitive the code is.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the full definition of the copy constructor but I assume that the `parent = other.parent` line is in there. In that case, wouldn't the parent be responsible for its own lifetime and the `delete parent` in the destructor shouldn't exist at all.

Also note that you need to at least disable (private declaration) or implement the copy assignment operator.

Better still, use a `vector` of `vector` for your 2d array and let the language work for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to include it, but I do have an assignment operator defined. I've added it to the post above. And I really wish I could use a vector, but we have to do it the way defined (CS assignment). :-(

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not a direct answer, but you are going against best practices for C++.

It's easier and definitely more maintainable to use vectors for this problem.

```
size_t row_sz = 3;
size_t col_sz = 3;
std::vector<int> board(row_sz * col_sz, 0);

int i = 0;
for (size_t r = 0; r < 0; r++)
for (size_t c = 0; c < 0; c++)
  board[ r * row_sz + c ] = i++;
```

Multidimensional arrays are much easier handled with the above strategy as well.  It just breaks less.  If you really want the row/col access, write a wrapper around it.

```
struct Matrix {
  int &operator()(size_t r, size_t c);
  const int &operator()(size_t r, size_t c) const;

private:
  std::vector<int> data;
};
```

Comment: I've edited my question to include the information, thank you for making me be more specific! :: we are required by the specification to use int**. :-(

Comment: @TylerBell Well it's there in case someone stumbles upon it with google.  For what it's worth, no one in industry would ask you to use int** generally.  If I code reviewed an interface with that, I wouldn't even *tolerate* it.